# How to read the input message of read shell command using process builder

Tags: java

I was trying to execute a shell script using process builder. The shell script uses the 'read' shell command. But when I check the output stream of the shell script, the input message associated with the 'read' command is missing.
The shell script is as follows:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # script.sh
    # This scripts has an input argument
    echo Hello World
    read -p "Enter something: " val1
    echo First Name: $val1
    read -p "Enter something: " val2
    echo Last Name: $val2
    echo $val1 $val2 invoked $1
    echo  $1 "completed successfully"
```

When I manually run this script with the command

```
    ./script.sh install
```

the output on the terminal is as follows:

```
    Hello World
    Enter something: albin
    First Name: albin
    Enter something: suresh
    Last Name: suresh
    albin suresh invoked install
    install completed successfully
```

But when I run the same command using process builder, the "Enter something" commands are missing in the output. The output that I'm getting is as follows:

```
    Hello World
    First Name: albin
    Last Name: suresh
    albin suresh invoked install
    install completed successfully
```

Why is this happening and to which stream do those "Enter something:" messages go??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to google for bash `read` command and got this link: http://ss64.com/bash/read.html

> -p prompt : Display prompt, without a trailing newline, before attempting to read any input. **The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a terminal.**

Apparently if input is coming from non terminal as in your example prompt is not shown.